# Prove set equality using set builder notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $a,b\in G$ then the cosets $(ab)H=a(bH)$.

This obviously follows from associativity of group operation. But a formal proof should show first that $(ab)H\subseteq a(bH)$ and then $a(bH)\subseteq(ab)H$. However, I think an easier proof is this:

$$ (ab)H = \{(ab)h\mid h\in H\}$$
$$ = \{ a(bh)\mid h\in H\}$$
$$ = a \{bh \mid h\in H\}$$
$$ = a(bH).$$

Are we allowed to prove using set builder notation like this?

Comment: Looks good to me. In general $H$ need to be a subgroup of $G$ for $(ab)H = a(bH)$ to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine. If you were to phrase it as a double inclusion proof, you would see that it is the exact same proof, just written slightly differently:

\begin{align}
x \in (ab)H &\iff x = (ab)h && \text{for some }h \in H,\\
&\iff x = a(bh),\\
&\iff x \in a(bH).
\end{align}